# Angulr2+ : ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges when route

Tags: angular

getting this error ,

> "ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges"

when i am trying to route from my list component to employee detail component, I called function and pass id , it is routed perfectly but in console giving me this error

Both the Component are in same module, employee module,

> EmployeeModule(EmployeeListComponent  => EmployeeProfileComponent)

code

```
editEmployee(emp){
   console.log('employee:=>',emp);
  this.route.navigate(['employee/profile'],{queryParams:{empid:emp.id}})
}
```

Comment: from which component you are navigating to profile page?

Comment: list component to edit component, and the function is in list component

Comment: Are you calling detectChanges somewhere in your code? Please post the code.